# How can I guarantee that function returns a value before created secondary thread ended its work?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

```
NSOperation *operation = /*some operation*/;
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];

// …
// Some work
// …

return Value;
```

I want to get *Value* from function before *operation* ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't.
You *may* wait for an operation to *be* done, but trying to ***preempt*** a threadpool task is somewhat pointless.
Even if you managed to pause/suspend the queue before you add your `operation`, you still have to resume it *before* you `return`, and you have no way to avoid a possible context switch at this point.
If the `Value` being returned is a shared var/global/field which might get modified by the operation, you may copy/clone its current value into a tempvar/local *before* the `addOperation` to return it later.